# NearbyBackgroundBeacons demo returns unknown status code 2801 on subscribe

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-nearby

I am testing Nearby Messages API using the Google NearbyBackgroundBeacons sample,

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-
nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyBackgroundBeacons

As documented in the README, i created an API key and placed the same in AndroidManifest.xml. My Estimote Beacon is configured for EddyStone-UID. It is registered using Google Proximity API and status is ACTIVE.

When i run the NearbyBackgroundBeacons demo on Samsung Galaxy S4, API 19, Android 4.4.4, play services 8.4.89, i see this following error

> 02-29 07:08:55.363
>   18073-18073/com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.samples.nearbybackgroundbeacons
>   E/MainActivityFragment: Could not resolve error. Status:
>   Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 2801, resolution=null}

when calling

```
Nearby.Messages.subscribe(GoogleApiClient, PendingIntent, SubscribeOptions)
```

Comment: That error code corresponds to TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS which triggers when you have > 5 pending intents for a single client app. You have to remove some with unsubscribe (or clear Google Play Services data ...) Do you get this on the first run on a fresh device or on the 6th run?

Comment: That's correct. Initially i was getting API_PERMISSION_DENIED for a few times and then i started seeing this error. I added the API key in AndroidManifest.xml. Any ideas why i still might be getting permission denied error?

Comment: Hi i am getting the same error , you found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

2801 is [`TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.html#TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS), in `NearbyMessagesStatusCodes`.

Use [`NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/NearbyMessagesStatusCodes.html#getStatusCodeString(int)) instead of the one in `CommonStatusCodes`. It will properly convert both Nearby codes and Common codes.

Comment: Yes. I started getting this error after i got permission denied errors a few times. I am not sure why i got that error either, since i have the API key in the manifest.